# Python 3.4.2:Converting data in a text file into a dictionary within a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, text-files

i'm creating a simple trouble shooting program where I want to store both keywords and solutions in a list within a text  file and then i want to extract this data and put it into a dictionary so that i can use it for the rest of the code(checking for key words).

The text file will look something like this:

```
iphone,put your phone in rice, wet, water, puddle
iphone,replace your screen, cracked, screen, smashed
iphone,turn off your phone,heat,heated,hot,fire
samsung,put your phone in rice, wet, water, puddle
samsung,replace your screen, cracked, screen, smashed
samsung,turn off your phone,heat,heated,hot,fire
```

The first part of the line is the phone model and the next is the solution and the  corresponding items are key words for that solution.

I would like the dictionary to look something like this:

```
dictionary = {"iphone":{"put your phone in rice":["wet","water","puddle"],
                        "replace your screen":["cracked","screen","smashed"],
                        "turn off your phone":["heat","heated","hot","fire"]
                        }
              "samsung":{"put your phone in rice":["wet","water","puddle"],
                        "replace your screen":["cracked","screen","smashed"],
                        "turn off your phone":["heat","heated","hot","fire"]
                        }
              }
```

In the actual thing the solutions would be different for each device.

I have been looking for a while and know that solving my solution would look something like this :

```
for i in data:
    dictionary[i[0]] = data[i[0:]]
```

where data is the text file imported. This code definitely doesn't work but i know that a possible solution will something on lines of this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're close:

```
dictionary = {}
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        phone, key, *rest = line.strip().split(",")
        if phone not in dictionary:
            dictionary[phone] = {}
        dictionary[phone][key] = rest
```

Instead of doing `phone, key, *rest = ...`, you could indeed do what you tried:

```
data = line.strip().split(",")
dictionary[data[0]][data[1]] = data[2:]
```

But I think tuple packing is easier and looks better.

To make it less annoying, you can use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dictionary = defaultdict(dict)
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        phone, key, *rest = line.strip().split(",")
        dictionary[phone][key] = rest
```